# Unable to set variable as a script for C-shell

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, csh, tcsh

This is very simple. I am trying to set my variable in a second script. I have tried multiple ways but does not work. Hence all the commented out section. The first script you run IE:unit3.2a.sh 3 5  this would return 8. The second script should read the result as 8. I am using cygwin.

unit3.2a.sh
'''

```
#!/bin/csh

set a = 0
set b = 0
set c = 0

@ a = $1
@ b = $2

@ c = $a + $b

echo $c
```

'''

unit3.sh
'''

```
#!/bin/csh

a=$(~./unit3.2a.sh)
#below is all that don't work!
#instructors: a =~./unit3.2a.sh 2 200
#./unit3.2a.sh "2" "200"
#~./unit3.2a.sh 2 200
#=$(./unit3.2a.sh 2 200)
#=$(./unit3.2a.sh)+(2 200)
#$(./unit3.2a.sh 2 200)
#$(/home/Admin/unit3.2a.sh)
#$(/home/Admin/unit3.2a.sh 2 200)
#added echo $a to see if I wasnt seeing  anything the echo text works fine but a variable does not read?
#set a='./unit3.2a.sh 2 200'
##set a=$(cat ./unit3.2a.sh 2 200)
#$ ./unit3.sh
#cat: 2: No such file or directory
#cat: 200: No such file or directory
#set a=$(~./unit3.2a.sh 2 200)
#a=$(~./unit3.2a.sh 2 200)



echo $a

echo "The result is: $a"

echo "Storing the results.............."

echo "Storing the result: $a" >> unit3.txt

echo "The script is over"
```

'''

Comment: I'm not clear about your use-case here, but do you know about `csh`'s `setenv` vs `set` and their differences? `setenv` is like `export` in other shells. It makes variables visible to child processes of the parent `csh`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please note that:

`~./unit3.2a.sh` is referring to a specific file location
while `./unit3.2a.sh` is referring to the file in the current directory

the form `$( command )` is bash specific, does not work in C shell, see
https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-21

```
#!/bin/csh

set a = `./unit3.2a.sh 2 2`

echo $a
echo "The result is: $a"
echo "Storing the results.............."
echo "Storing the result: $a" >> unit3.txt
echo "The script is over"
```

that produces:

```
$ ./unit3.sh
4
The result is: 4
Storing the results..............
The script is over
```

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the article, I understand python, java, and c. But linux is kicking my two-pack. It is just different enough from cmd prompt its like I know french, so i understand a lot of spanish, when reading but hearing no clue. :) Thank you.